# Confution on UV cut-off in the calculation of effective action and Beta function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, regularization

I am reading David Tong's [gauge theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/gt.pdf) and meet some difficulties.

In section 2.4.2, he uses background field to calculate effective action $S_{eff}$ and Beta function. Simply like follows:
Writting gauge field $A_{\mu}$ as $A_{\mu}=\bar{A}_{\mu}+\delta A_{\mu}$ for $\bar{A}_{\mu}$ being a fixed field, $\delta A_{\mu}$ being fluctuation. Also we introduce Faddeev-Popov ghost fields $c$ and $c^{\dagger}$. The path integral of gauge field $A_{\mu}$ goes like
\begin{equation}
e^{-S_{eff}}=Z=\int \mathcal{D}A \mathcal{D}c \mathcal{D}c^{\dagger}e^{S(A,c,c^{\dagger})}=(\det[\Delta_{gauge}])^{-1/2} \det[\Delta_{ghost}]e^{(-1/2g^2) S_{YM}(\bar{A})}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
S_{YM}(A)=\int d^4x tr(F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu \nu}) .
\end{equation}
So the effective action $S_{eff}$ is then
\begin{equation}
S_{eff}=\frac{1}{2g^2}S_{YM}(\bar{A})+\frac{1}{2}Tr\log\Delta_{gauge}-Tr\log\Delta_{ghost}
\end{equation}
See eq(2.63) in the notes.

Now he gets the contribution of $-Tr\log\Delta_{ghost}$ (see page 71 in the notes) as
\begin{equation}
-Tr\log\Delta_{ghost}=constant \times \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}tr(\bar{A}_{\mu}(k)\bar{A}_{\nu}(-k))(k^{\mu}k^{\nu}-k^2\delta^{\mu\nu})\log\bigg(\frac{\Lambda^2}{k^2}\bigg).
\end{equation}

**Here is what I don't understand**: how does this $\log\bigg(\frac{\Lambda^2}{k^2}\bigg)$ appear in our integral in terms of $\log$? Is it a regularization? If it is, then the integrand cannot turn back to $tr(\bar{A}_{\mu}(k)\bar{A}_{\nu}(-k))(k^{\mu}k^{\nu}-k^2\delta^{\mu\nu})$ under limit $\Lambda=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Tong is using a cutoff regularization in this calculation, the cutoff being this $\Lambda$. Specifically this factor appears because he has just completed the loop momenta integral (integral over the momenta $p$). This integral is divergent without a regularization scheme, so of course taking $\Lambda\rightarrow\infty$ (removing the cutoff) will cause the what you have written to diverge.